# Db import error phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Hi im migrating a website for a company as one of the partners has "gone rogue". Im trying to import an sql dump file into phpmyadmin and get the following error.

SQL query:

```
"-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.34, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)"
--
#NAME?
-- ------------------------------------------------------
"-- Server version  5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1"

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib     5.5.34, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)"
--
#NAME?' at line 1
```

Can anybodyhelp.

Thanks in advance David

Comment: I think it might be the quotations. Can you show us more of a sample of your dump?

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange looking dump file. In particular, the double quotes `"` on lines 1 and 5 and the `#NAME?` make no sense to me and I can't imagine why they're there.

Any chance to regenerate the dump? If not, the immediate solution is to simply edit out those lines, but at the risk that there might be more further along in the file. You can remove the double-quotes from the two lines you show and completely delete the `#NAME?` line.

The only time I've ever seen the text like `#NAME?` is with Excel, and it makes no sense to work with Excel on an SQL file (even if you were, I don't know how this would have ended up here like this), so I'm not sure where it's coming from, but hopefully by editing in your text editor you can at least import the data.